# FFT using Python - unexpected low frequencies

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, fft

I'm still trying to get frequency analysis for this [data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7um2WC4G6FFazF1eXJHRVNqVFU) using FFT in Python.
The sampling rate is 1 data point per minute.

My code is:

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft
df3 = pd.read_csv('Pressure - Dates by Minute.csv', sep=",", skiprows=0)
df3['Pressure FFT'] = df3['ATMOSPHERIC PRESSURE (hPa) mean'] - df3['ATMOSPHERIC PRESSURE (hPa) mean'].mean()
Pressure = df3['Pressure FFT']
Fs = 1/60
Ts = 1.0/Fs
n = len(Pressure)
k = np.arange(n)
T = n/Fs
t = np.arange(0,1,1/n) # time vector
frq = k/T # two sides frequency range
frq = frq[range(int(n/2))] # one side frequency range

Y = np.fft.fft(Pressure)/n # fft computing and normalization
Y = Y[range(int(n/2))]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)
ax[0].plot(t,Pressure)
ax[0].set_xlabel('Time')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Amplitude')
ax[1].plot(frq,abs(Y),'r') # plotting the spectrum
ax[1].set_xlabel('Freq (Hz)')
ax[1].set_ylabel('|Y(freq)|')
```

But the result gives:

[image]

So my problems are:

1) Why there are no frequencies at all ? The data is clearly periodic.

2) Why the frequency spectrum is so low ? (0 - 0.009)

3) Maybe I should try different filtering technique?

Any insights ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: The first item in the array returned by the FFT function has the DC component, i.e. the sum of all values in the original array.  This is often orders of magnitude larger than the periodic components.  Try plotting `Y[1:]` , or doing `Y[0] = 0` before plotting, and you should see your frequencies show up.

Comment: I've tried doing Y[0] = 0  before plotting, but still no frequencies. maybe it's the normalization ? since the periodic behavior is twice a day .

Comment: Typically you want to plot the Y axis using a log scale. Also you forgot to apply a suitable window function prior to the FFT.

Comment: Why do I need a window function ? How would it help ?

Comment: A window function will help to reduce spectral leakage and artefacts introduced by the discontinuity between the start and end point of your sample window - these will be much more noticeable when you use a log scale for the Y axis.

Comment: It looks like you have many data points that are much closer together that than fluctuations in your data.  Therefore, all of your structure is in the low frequencies.  That, I think, is your answer.  Overall, though, you're asking several basic questions about FFTs.  This isn't a programming question so much as a request for a tutorial, and is off topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Why there are no frequencies at all ? The data is clearly periodic.

Well, there is frequency content, it's just not exactly visible because of its structure. Try changing the line that plots the frequency spectrum, from `ax[1].plot(frq,abs(Y),'r')` to `ax[1].semilogy(frq,abs(Y),'r')`

This will result to:

[image: semilog Spectrum]

Where we have now applied a simple transformation that boosts low values and limits high values. For more information please see [this link](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/pixlog.htm). Of course, having removed the DC (as you do on line 3 of your code) helps too.

This still seems a bit blurry and it is, but if we zoom in to the lower part of the spectrum, we see this:

[image: semilog Transform]

Which shows a spike at approximately 2.3e-05 Hz which corresponds to approximately 12 hours.

> 2) Why the frequency spectrum is so low ? (0 - 0.009)

Because you sample once every 60 seconds, therefore your sampling frequency is (approximately) 0.016 Hz. Your spectrum contains everything between DC (0Hz) and 0.0083Hz. For more information, please see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency)

> 3) Maybe I should try different filtering technique?

You can try windowing if you can't resolve a harmonic but it doesn't look like it's needed here.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the reason why those frequencies seem so low is because the time axis in your amplitude plot is scaled weirdly. If you really have one sample per 60 seconds then the x-axis should range between 0 and 1690260 seconds (i.e. ~20 days!).

[image]

By eye, you seem to have about one small peak every 50000 seconds (~2 per day), which would correspond to a frequency of about 2x10⁻⁵ Hz. Your periodogram therefore looks pretty reasonable to me, given how massive the scale of the x-axis is.